# Android: fit each item of a listview per screen

Tags: android, listview

I want to fit each item/row of the screen per screen. But I am specifying height and width in dp for xml of row for implementing that. Sine I am specifying height/width, each row is not fitting exactly the screen and also not for all type of screen resolution. How I will achieve that?Can anybody please give idea on that?

**Here is the xml file:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="1024dip"
android:layout_height="480dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView android:layout_width="1024dip"
android:layout_height="480dip" 
android:text="ViewSwitcher" 
android:textSize="20sp" 
android:gravity="center" 
android:padding="10dip" 
android:background="#404040" 
android:id="@+id/textView" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="1024dip" android:layout_height="480dip"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
 <TextView android:layout_width="1024dip"
  android:layout_height="480dip" android:text="ViewSwitcher"
  android:textSize="20sp" android:gravity="center" android:padding="10dip"
  android:background="#404040" android:id="@+id/textView" />

</LinearLayout>
This is my row.xml

Comment: @eager-Add xml file in question so that everyone see at first glance..!!!

Comment: By specifying fixed height to layout,you might not getting the desired output to every android device.For that use fill_parent. :)

Comment: It is not working using fill_parent for listview!!!!

Comment: Please give your listview code in xml so can give you best answer..

Comment: @eager-Refer my Edit..!!

Answer (score 1):

Please make use of the linear layout, by using the feature of weightsum with which u can divide the scren resolution to any extent...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these two instead of specifying the dpi's

```
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Comment: no. it's not working. that's why i am specifying width/height

Comment: u gave this for both linear layout and text view?

Comment: Only for linearlayout it will not effect anything. If I give for textview it will reflect. i can use fill_parent for linearlayout. Sorry it was the testing code...

Comment: umm. It is not working using listview. So I am now using viewpager and customized it as vertical. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you worked with **LazyAdapter**.

Try this...

**Demo.java:**

```
public class Demo extends Activity {

LazyAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo_layout);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayList<String> songsList = new ArrayList<String>();

        songsList.add("Song 1");
        songsList.add("Song 2");
        songsList.add("Song 3");

        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}   

 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        //Do Something here
    }

}
```

**demo_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**LazyAdapter.java:**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<String> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> d) {

    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lazyadapter_layout, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title

    String song;
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song);

    return vi;
}
}
```

**lazyadapter_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="480dp"
        android:background="#404040"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ViewSwitcher"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps you !!!

For more details [refer this tutorial.](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I have to specify width/height.So I am now using viewpager and customized it as vertical.

Comment: @eager- I would ave given u that advice first...but I thought let me try for list first..!!!

Comment: @eager- And if u want to specify width/height, then specify it in lazyadapter_layout.xml in TextView..!!

Comment: @nilayonAndrod- sorry for late respond. I don't want to specify width and height. But if I use layout, I have to specify. I tried using lazyadapter xml.That's why I gave up of using listview!!